# The content of element type "person" is incomplete, it must match (familyname,firstname,city?,telephone+)"

Tags: xml, dtd, xml-validation

im watching at my code since 2 hours ago, and still didn't figure out where i am doing a mistake, basicly i have a dtd and a xml in the same file and when i go to the xmlvalidator i always get the error on the title.

**here is the code**

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE addressbook [

<!ELEMENT addressbook (person*)>
<!ELEMENT person (familyname,firstname,city?,telephone+)>
<!ELEMENT familyname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT firstname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT telephone (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST person id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST telephone type CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>

<addressbook>
    <person id="p01">
        <familyname>De Niro</familyname>
        <firstname>Roberto</firstname>
        <city>Los Angeles</city>
        <telephone type="mobile">123456</telephone>
    </person>
    <person id="p02">
        <familyname>Bale</familyname>
        <firstname>Gareth</firstname>
        <city>Madrid</city>
        <telephone>987654</telephone>
    </person>
    <person id="p03">
        <familyname>Jobs</familyname>
        <firstname>Steve</firstname>
        <city>Palo Alto</city>
    </person>
    <person id="p04">
        <familyname>Fry</familyname>
        <firstname>Stephen</firstname>
        <telephone type="landline">132867</telephone>
        <telephone type="mobile">725282</telephone>
    </person>
</addressbook>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your third `<person>` element doesn't have a telephone number:

```
<person id="p03">
    <familyname>Jobs</familyname>
    <firstname>Steve</firstname>
    <city>Palo Alto</city>
</person>
```

However, your DTD requires one or more telephone numbers:

```
<!ELEMENT person (familyname,firstname,city?,telephone+)>
```

You need to either add a telephone number to that `<person>` element or change the content model to allow zero or more telephone numbers:

```
<!ELEMENT person (familyname,firstname,city?,telephone*)>
```